# MouseListener being unresponsive

Tags: java, mouseevent, mouselistener

The MouseListener for my game that handles the shooting is being unresponsive when using an seperate mouse but not when using the built in mouse on my laptop. In my player class the mouseClicked method looks like this:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
    if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1){
        fire();
    }
}
```

and in a seperate class that extends JPanel I implement the MouseListener like this:

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            player.mouseClicked(e);
        }
    });
```

I have always used my built in mouse for coding and testing the game and every time I clicked the left mouse button the player started shooting but now when I wanted to try to play throuh the game with my mouse I noticed that the player didn't start shooting everytime I pressed the left mouse button but more like 80% of the time.

Comment: The fact that is intermittent indicates somethings wrong with your mouse itself. I would try to put either a debug breakpoint or a debug log statement in the mouse listener and try to figure out it the breakpoint is hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I noticed that the player didn't start shooting everytime I pressed the left mouse button but more like 80% of the time.

Try using `mousePressed()` instead of mouseClicked(). A mouseClicked event is only generated when a mousePressed() and mouseReleased() event is generated at the same location. Maybe you are moving the mouse a pixel or two so the mouseClicked event doesn't get generated.

```
if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
```

Also, instead of the above use the following which is easier to read:

```
if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e))
```